# How to configure GSSAPI Login?

Tags: authentication, kerberos, rapidclipse

I have searched about how to provide an active directory/LDAP based login for my Java web application. In this forum are also approx. 100+ tickets, which I did not understand, or which did not have same target like I. I tried several configurations.

With following code I had the best result, but still not getting it completely working.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;


@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class LdapAuth
{
private final static String ldapURI            = "ldap://XXX.XXX.XXX.X:389";  //LDAP Server IP
private final static String contextFactory     = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
private static String[]     requiredAttributes = {"cn", "givenName", "sn", "displayName", "userPrincipalName",
    "sAMAccountName", "objectSid", "userAccountControl"};

private static String[] ADSearchPaths =
    {
        "CN=Users"
    };


public static void authenticateUserAndGetInfo(final String user, final String password) throws Exception
{
    try
    {

        final ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        final String      fullPath    = classLoader.getResource("/META-INF/krb5.conf").getPath();
        System.out.println(fullPath);

        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.spnego.debug", "true");

        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", fullPath);
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.principal", user);
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName", user + "@MY.DOMAIN");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.Credentials", password);
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");

        final Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, LdapAuth.contextFactory);

        env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, LdapAuth.ldapURI);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "GSSAPI");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");
        env.put(Context.AUTHORITATIVE, "false");

        final DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

        String filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + user + ")"; // default for search filter username

        if(user.contains("@")) // if user name is a email then
        {
            // String parts[] = user.split("\\@");
            // use different filter for email
            filter = "(userPrincipalName=" + user + ")";
        }

        final SearchControls ctrl = new SearchControls();
        ctrl.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        ctrl.setReturningAttributes(LdapAuth.requiredAttributes);

        NamingEnumeration userInfo = null;

        Integer i = 0;
        do
        {
            userInfo = ctx.search(LdapAuth.ADSearchPaths[i], filter, ctrl);
            i++;
        }
        while(!userInfo.hasMore() && i < LdapAuth.ADSearchPaths.length);

        if(userInfo.hasMore())
        {
            final SearchResult UserDetails = (SearchResult)userInfo.next();
            final Attributes   userAttr    = UserDetails.getAttributes();
            System.out.println("adEmail = " + userAttr.get("userPrincipalName").get(0).toString());
            System.out.println("adFirstName = " + userAttr.get("givenName").get(0).toString());
            System.out.println("adLastName = " + userAttr.get("sn").get(0).toString());
            System.out.println("name = " + userAttr.get("cn").get(0).toString());
            System.out.println("AdFullName = " + userAttr.get("cn").get(0).toString());
        }

        userInfo.close();

    }
    catch(final javax.naming.AuthenticationException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

As AD-Controller I use a synology AD package. I tried out simple authentication, but this did not work.

I got an error:

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 8 - BindSimple: Transport encryption required.]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
...
```

Additional Information. With klist on client console I got two tickets for my user. And I am able to login from client console by ssh on AD-Controller with success

After changing and setting System.setProperty .... 6 lines
and setting instead of simple:

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "GSSSAPI");
```

I got following output and I was asked on console for the Kerberos Userid.

```
>>>KinitOptions cache name is C:\Users\myuser\krb5cc_myuser
>> Acquire default native Credentials
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23.
>>> Found no TGT's in LSA
Kerberos-Password für myUserId: mySecretPassword
         ########################################
>>> KdcAccessibility: reset
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23.
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=XXX.XXX.XXX.X TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=126
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=XXX.XXX.XXX.X TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=126
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 248 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=248
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 2
 PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 16

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 15

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 11
 PA-ETYPE-INFO etype = 23, salt = null

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 19
 PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 23, salt = null, s2kparams = null

>>> KdcAccessibility: remove XXX.XXX.XXX.X:88
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 11
>>>KRBError:
 sTime is Sat Mar 07 16:49:32 CET 2020 1583596172000
 suSec is 184771
 error code is 25
 error Message is Additional pre-authentication required
 cname is myUserId@my.domain
 sname is krbrAdmin/my.domain@MY.DOMAIN
 eData provided.
 msgType is 30
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 2
 PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 16

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 15

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 11
 PA-ETYPE-INFO etype = 23, salt = null

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
 PA-DATA type = 19
 PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 23, salt = null, s2kparams = null

KRBError received: Need to use PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP/PA-PK-AS-REQ
KrbAsReqBuilder: PREAUTH FAILED/REQ, re-send AS-REQ
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23.
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=XXX.XXX.XXX.X TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=206
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=XXX.XXX.XXX.X TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=206
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 1186 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=1186
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove XXX.XXX.XXX.X:88
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>> KrbAsRep cons in KrbAsReq.getReply hri4wa1
Found ticket for myUserId@MY.DOMAIN to go to krbrAdmin/my.domain@MY.DOMAIN expiring on Sun Mar 08 02:49:32 CET 2020
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Service ticket not found in the subject
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: same realm
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 23.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=XXX.XXX.XXX.X TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=1225
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=XXX.XXX.XXX.X TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=1225
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 107 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=107
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove XXX.XXX.XXX.X:88
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 13
```

After this output I got following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty nameStrings not allowed
    at sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName.validateNameStrings(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to figure out how to prevent this: Also without success
Also setting

```
    System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName", user + "@MY.DOMAIN");
```

did still not work.

Also additional information, my server supports:

{supportedsaslmechanisms=supportedSASLMechanisms: GSS-SPNEGO, GSSAPI, NTLM}

I feel that there are more than one issue to get it running. One what I am also not sure is, will it be required to configure my tomcat in any way?

Comment: `Transport encryption required` probably means that AD requires SSL/TLS encryption, especially to **protect passwords** otherwise sent in plain text (deep sigh). Try with `ldaps://****:636` (LDAP + SSL) or keep  `ldap://***:389` but activate the "StartTLS" connection flag -- but beware, you will also need to set up your application to accept the server certificate _(unless it uses a public authority such as Verisign or Let's Encrypt)_

Comment: Kerberos is black magic. The Java implementation is crude and incomplete. Microsoft added custom "extensions" that make interoperability a bit difficult. Avoid Kerberos unless you have an expert available to do the dirty work for you -- or you have 2 man-months to spend on self-education.

Comment: I still tried ldaps...:636 also without success. After adding a jaas.conf file I got the connection without errors, but always with feedback wrong user/passwd. :-(
But still aggree with black magic...:-)

Comment: Now I added in my AD Controller smb.conf:<br> 
ldap server require strong auth = No<br>
Now I get the connection and password seems to be validated but I get now: a NamingException. But I have to analyse deeper.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to solve it with oauth/azure ad. Its not LDAP - however it might be interesting anyway.
Have a look: https://github.com/xware-gmbh/SeicentoBilling

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the working code for OpenLDAP login**

```
public void checkUserCredential(final LDAPPojo ldapPojo)
{
    this.contextSetPropertiesUtilityPOJO =
        this.contextSetPropertiesUtility.ContextSetProperties(this.contextSetPropertiesUtilityPOJO);
    this.log.info(UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(ConfigProperties.SESSION_KEY)
        + "::LDAPCreateUserUtility::checkUserCredential::");
    
    this.log.info(UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(ConfigProperties.SESSION_KEY)
        + "::LDAPCreateUserUtility::checkUserCredential::get LDAP Provider URL: "
        + this.contextSetPropertiesUtilityPOJO.getLDAP_PROVIDER_URL());
    
    try
    {
        final Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, ConfigProperties.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, this.contextSetPropertiesUtilityPOJO.getLDAP_PROVIDER_URL());
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ConfigProperties.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, ConfigProperties.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapPojo.getUserName());
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapPojo.getPassword());
        
        new InitialDirContext(env).close();
        ldapPojo.setReturnFlag(ResourceProperty.errorCodeBundle.getString("PASSWORD_MATCHES_CODE"));
    }
    catch(final NamingException e)
    {
        this.log.error(UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(ConfigProperties.SESSION_KEY)
            + "::LDAPCreateUserUtility::checkUserCredential::Exception: " + e.getStackTrace(), e);
        ldapPojo.setReturnFlag(ResourceProperty.messagesBundle.getString("PASSWORD_DOES_NOT_MATCH_MSG"));
    }
    catch(final Exception ex)
    {
        this.log.error(UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(ConfigProperties.SESSION_KEY)
            + "::LDAPCreateUserUtility::checkUserCredential::Exception: " + ex.getStackTrace(), ex);
        ldapPojo.setReturnFlag(ResourceProperty.messagesBundle.getString("PASSWORD_DOES_NOT_MATCH_MSG"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is code to create users through java**

```
private void addUser(final DirContext ctx, final LDAPPojo ldapPojo)
{

    this.log.info(UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(ConfigProperties.SESSION_KEY)
        + "::LDAPCreateUserUtility::addUser::");
    try
    {
        
        final Attributes                            attributes = new BasicAttributes();
        final javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute objClasses = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
        
        // WARNING: DO NOT TOUCH
        objClasses.add("inetOrgPerson");
        objClasses.add("posixAccount");
        objClasses.add("top");
        attributes.put(objClasses);
        
        // Define User attributes
        attributes.put(ConfigProperties.LDAP_KEY_LOGIN_SHELL, ldapPojo.getLoginShell());
        attributes.put(ConfigProperties.LDAP_KEY_GIVEN_NAME, ldapPojo.getFirstName());
        attributes.put(ConfigProperties.LDAP_KEY_HOME_DIRECTORY, ldapPojo.getHomeDirectory());
        attributes.put(ConfigProperties.LDAP_KEY_UID, ldapPojo.getUid());
        attributes.put(ConfigProperties.LDAP_KEY_UID_NUMBER, ldapPojo.getUidNumber());
        attributes.put(ConfigProperties.LDAP_KEY_GID_NUMBER, ldapPojo.getGidNumber());
        attributes.put(ConfigProperties.LDAP_KEY_SN, ldapPojo.getSn());
        attributes.put(ConfigProperties.LDAP_KEY_CN, ldapPojo.getCn());
        attributes.put(ConfigProperties.LDAP_KEY_PASSWORD, ldapPojo.getPassword());
        
        this.log.info(UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(ConfigProperties.SESSION_KEY)
            + "::LDAPCreateUserUtility::addUser::Sub Context: " + ldapPojo.getSubContext());
        ctx.createSubcontext(ldapPojo.getSubContext(), attributes);
        
        this.log.info(UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(ConfigProperties.SESSION_KEY)
            + "::LDAPCreateUserUtility::addUser::success");
        ldapPojo.setReturnFlag(ResourceProperty.configBundle.getString("RETURN_TRUE_FLAG"));
    }
    catch(final Exception e)
    {
        this.log.error(UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(ConfigProperties.SESSION_KEY)
            + "::LDAPCreateUserUtility::addUser::Exception: " + e.getStackTrace(), e);
        this.log.error(UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(ConfigProperties.SESSION_KEY)
            + "::LDAPCreateUserUtility::addUser::exception_for_user_LDAP >> " + ldapPojo.getUid());
        ldapPojo.setReturnFlag(ResourceProperty.messagesBundle.getString("LDAP_USER_CREATION_ERROR_MSG"));
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            this.log.info(UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(ConfigProperties.SESSION_KEY)
                + "::LDAPCreateUserUtility::addUser::pstmt closed");
        }
        catch(final Exception ignore)
        {
            this.log.error(UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(ConfigProperties.SESSION_KEY)
                + "::LDAPCreateUserUtility::addUser::Exception: " + ignore.getStackTrace(), ignore);
            ldapPojo.setReturnFlag(ResourceProperty.messagesBundle.getString("LDAP_USER_CREATION_ERROR_MSG"));
        }
    }
}
public void createLDAPUser(final LDAPPojo ldapPojo)
{
    this.log.info(UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(ConfigProperties.SESSION_KEY)
        + "::LDAPCreateUserUtility::createLDAPUser::");
    try
    {
        final Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, ConfigProperties.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, this.contextSetPropertiesUtilityPOJO.getLDAP_PROVIDER_URL());
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ConfigProperties.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, ConfigProperties.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, this.contextSetPropertiesUtilityPOJO.getLDAP_ROOT_LOGIN_USER());
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, this.contextSetPropertiesUtilityPOJO.getLDAP_ROOT_LOGIN_PASSWORD());
        this.addUser((new InitialDirContext(env)), ldapPojo);
        
    }
    catch(final Exception exception)
    {
        this.log.error(UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(ConfigProperties.SESSION_KEY)
            + "::LDAPCreateUserUtility::addUser::Exception: " + exception.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```